# Gradle: Execution failed for task. Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details

Tags: java, android, кодировка, gradle, компилятор

Добрый день!
Неожиданная проблема возникла при сборке проекта. Выдает вот такую ошибку в файле класса R

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Gradle: error: illegal character: \8212
Gradle: error: <identifier> expected
```

Ссылаясь на строку в файле

```
public static final int city_сhooser_no_internet_exception_text=0x7f0c002e;
```

И я вообще в замешательстве, кодировка файла UTF-8, пробовал даже менять, но безуспешно :(

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что строки в ресурсах могут содержать в себе далеко не все символы, особенно, если эти символы не юникод.

Третья строчка приведенного вами лога говорит о том, что строка содержит недопустимый символ с номером 8212:

```
Gradle: error: illegal character: \u8212
```

Для проверки вышесказанного замените строку `city_сhooser_no_internet_exception_text` на что-либо более адекватное. Например, "abcd" и проверьте результат.

**Для справки:**

Так, в ресурсах нельзя, например, хранить в незакодированном виде символы вроде `"<" и ">"`. Их необходимо экранировать: `"&lt;"` и `"&gt;"` и т.д

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в ресурсах посмотреть, что в `xml`-файле у тебя творится, где прописано значение для `city_сhooser_no_internet_exception_text` Наверняка - там увидишь причину... А файлы R руками вообще не правят, они генерятся автоматически.

Comment: файлу  R.java никто не правил. Проблема уже давно решена. Как решил не помню, прошло уже больше года.